# how to specify network name in app.yaml for asp.net core webapi deployed in Google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy an asp.net core webapi to google appengine flex. If you don't mention network name in app.yaml then it takes default.

In my case there is no default network. I have to explicitly specify the network name and subnetwork_name in my app.yaml. This project where I am trying to deploy my api in appengine flex is in a shared VPC.This is why I am specifying the complete path, "projects/myorg-npe-232f/global/networks/myorg-shared-network". Please refer the app.yaml below -

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
service: default
api_version: 1.1
network:
    name: projects/myorg-npe-232f/global/networks/myorg-shared-network
    subnetwork_name: myorg-exxc-bbdf-subnet-central
```

I am getting the below error -

```
Unable to assign value 'projects/myorg-npe-232f/global/networks/myorg-shared-network' to attribute 'name':

value 'projects/myorg-npe-232f/global/networks/myorg-shared-network' for name does not match expression '^(?:^[a-z]([a-z\d-]{0,61}[a-z\d])?$)$' in app.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#ineligible_resources):

> In a service project, App Engine Flexible resources cannot participate
>   in Shared VPC.

You may want to consider [VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) instead if it fits your use case.

Comment: I don't think this is still accurate: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-shared-vpc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppEngine flex, you can use the same settings.

However, make sure the vpc subnet exists, permissions and the firewall rule setup, I was getting the exact same error when I did not provide subnetwork_name.

Re: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-shared-vpc

```
network:
  name: projects/project-id/global/networks/myorg-shared-vpc
  session_affinity: true
  subnetwork_name: mycompany-develop-us-central1
```

Another update:
Found this same issue with a co-worker, fixed it by updating the cloud commandline client.

Answer (score 0):

Once the firewall rule and proper permissions are set up, can be deployed either a new or an existing of App Engine flexible ENV service into Shared VPC network, check the parameters in the manifest file:

```
network:
  name: projects/HOST_PROJECT_ID/global/networks/NETWORK_NAME
  subnetwork_name: SUBNETWORK_NAME
```